# Interrupted Time Series for Panel with Fixed Effects?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, python, intervention-analysis

I want to assess a specific type of event's impact on a business's revenue. For example, receiving first press coverage, etc.

I am thinking about interrupted time series analysis but I'm not sure how to use it for many time series--I have data for many businesses so it is more like panel data. Are there any packages or methods I should check out? I'm mainly doing this analysis in Python but I can do R too.

There are some data questions too:

1. The time they received the first coverage will differ (A received the first coverage in 2010/10 while B 2020/10).
2. The baseline of the revenue for each business will differ too (A could go from 400 to 700 while B goes from 50000 to 10000). I'm thinking about if I should have fixed effects, but I only used fixed effects in linear regression, not timer series ones.
3. Overall, there is a trend for revenues to grow for every business, so there will be autocorrelation.

I'm wondering what methods or data normalization are suited to answer my RQ. Right now I normalized the time to have the time series convert to a time index ranging from -6 to 6, with 0 being the value when the intervention happened (regardless of their actual date). I'm not sure how to do with 2, should I normalize the actual numbers to a relative percent increase or not?

Any insights will be helpful. I'm not very fixated on causal inference but want to explore rather than validate the impulse impact and generalize it with many time series.

Thanks in advance.